# Wordpress PHP half works on nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

under the path there are public files:

```
$/usr/share/nginx/html

50x.html     readme.html           wp-content         wp-mail.php
apc.php      wp-activate.php       wp-cron.php        wp-settings.php
hello.php    wp-admin              wp-includes        wp-signup.php
index.html   wp-blog-header.php    wp-links-opml.php  wp-trackback.php
index.php    wp-comments-post.php  wp-load.php        xmlrpc.php
license.txt  wp-config.php         wp-login.php
```

`apc.php` can work.

`html`s surely work.

`hello.php` returns text.

others return 504 Gateway timeout, or 502 Bad Gateway

and I can't find `phpmyadmin` anymore.

---

For more may relate:

at first I can visit `phpmyadmin`. but when moved wordpress files to `$/usr/share/nginx/html` (in order I can visit them!) this database entry mysteriously cannot be found.

Comment: What is the configuration for both `nginx` and `php-fpm`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks, sorry for late to reply. I got problems after moving directory - I shouldn't do that. Right way is to change default path in nginx config file, or it cannot find previous pages.